# Unable to get count from list of API flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am trying to get the count of users from this API in flutter(refer to code below), however whenever this function is executed, it gives me an error - Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

I have been stuck on this, your help would be highly appreciated.

```
Future getLeadsList() async {
var response = await http.get(
  Uri.https('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', 'users'),
);
var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

late List<Lead> leads = [];

for (var l in jsonData) {
  Lead lead = Lead(l["name"], l["username"], l["email"]);
  leads.add(lead);
}
print(leads.length);
return leads;
```

}

Comment: Depends on the "Lead" class. Can you share its code?

Comment: Are you sure that none of these values is null? l["name"], l["username"], l["email"]

Comment: @JorgeVieira no value is null, it's an open API, you can check there.

Comment: @AmirhosseinShahbazi, class Lead {
  late final String name, username, email;
  Lead(this.name, this.username, this.email);
}

Comment: There's no problem with it. I copied your code and printed out both the length and content of "leads".  works perfectly fine: https://pasteboard.co/Kef465i.png

Have you tested/printed jsonData and Does it contain the actual data?
The API call is working fine?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add null safety syntex,

```
for (var l in jsonData) {
  Lead lead = Lead(l["name"] ?? "", l["username"] ?? "", l["email"] ?? "");
  leads.add(lead);
}
```

Comment: np bro, vote the answer is useful plz ~ haha

Comment: my repo is low, they aren't counting my vote. :-(